# No option for recording conference in JITSI

Tags: jitsi, jitsi-meet

I install jitsi on my server (Debian 10.3). The server is located behind nat. jitsi works well. But in my conference no option for recording and translating the conference
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqF86.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the recording and Livestream option in `config.js`. Normally that file location is `/etc/jitsi/meet/<DOMAIN>-config.js`. After that, you have to manually enable these two options.